# change entity form header on field change in dynamics 365

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-365

I have an Entity called Assignment. The same entity is used for saving Sub-Assignments as well. Then only difference is that for Assignment Type, the choice field value will be 'Assignment' and for the Other it will be 'Sub-Assignment'. Now the form name(Header) is Assignment for both Assignment and Sub-Assignment. Is there any way to show the form name or tab-name as Assignment and Sub-Assignment based on the choice selected?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the "form" name, but you can change the tab name:

```js
formContext.ui.tabs.get(0).setLabel("Sub-Assignment");
```